# Issues with X11 and remote DISPLAY - when did the world change on me?

Tags: linux, x11

I'm fairly sure that I am not insane, but I do have memories of using X11 in the past (80's, 90's) and being able to set the display to anyplace I wanted to. Subject, of course, to access controls.

However, when I try it today on a modern O/S (Ubuntu 11.10 desktop,) for the life of me, I can not get it to work with a remote X server.

After a series of attempts, I decided to ensure that it even worked on my own computer. Shockingly, it didn't work locally either.  To wit:

- "**xterm**" works
- So do "**xterm -display :0**" and "**xterm -display :0.0**"
- But "**xterm -display my-ip-addr:0**" does not work
- And neither does "**xterm -display 127.0.0.1:0**"

Things I've already tried:

- "*xhost +*," (no flames about that, please)
- Setting "*DISPLAY=foo*" instead of "*-display foo*"

I know about ssh port forwarding, but for a number of reasons, that's not the solution I'm looking for.

What am I missing?

Comment: Good question, but this belongs on [su]

Comment: as datenwolf said, the X server is probably configured with a `-nolisten tcp`, which is probably somewhere on your display manager configuration.

Comment: "I'm fairly sure that I am not insane" - that is a bold statement Sir, I'm not brave enough to say the same about myself :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xhost based authentication is quite outdated. You can still enable it, but the common way for X authentication is through security cookies, contained in the X Authority file. The tool to access and manipulate it is called `xauth`. The trick is to extract the xauth authentication data on the machine running the X server and add it to the xauth data on the remote end.

However on most Linux systems the X server has been configured to not accept connections via TCP (which actually makes sense). Also the pure X protocoll doesn't provide confidentiality, so it's strongly discouraged to use it directly on the wire.

So to actually use this, you'll have to start an X server accepting tcp connections. You also tell the server a path were to place an initial X authority file. You then extract the xauth data from this and merge it into the ~/.Xauthority on the remote end.

Comment: I agree – `X -nolisten tcp` is a good modern default, and generally, using SSH or NX (which is really just X compression over SSH) to forward X is better in many ways than using plain X11 on the wire.

Comment: @ephemient: Actually using end-to-end IPSec you could use X11 over tcp in a secure manner just fine. Unfortunately not many people use it.

Comment: @ephemient: actually, NX is a bit more complex than your statement: _"X compression over SSH"_ would imply, IIRC it includes caching of properties to avoid round-trips, zeroing of unused protocol fields to achieve better compression, protocol-specific compression a la DXCP, zlib-based compression a la lbxproxy, ...

Comment: @ninjalj: And it compresses Pixmaps using JPEG. The problem is that "modern" toolkits are written by morons which render the whole window on a client side pixmap that's then sent to the graphics card. Total waste of good CPU cycles and the GPU twiddles thumbs.  There's also no reason, why XCore shouldn't be able to render its stuff with antialiasing. And coaxing a vector font renderer onto the server side of XCore isn't that infeasible either. But for some reason everything must be client side. Why not simply add a extension to allow a client to upload a font to the server.

Comment: @ninjalj: No I didn't. I'm honestly thinking that way. There's a lot of negative opinion about X11 "just because". There are a few itches in X11 that need some scratching, but none of them is so bad that it couldn't be fixed. The biggest problem of X11 is the convoluted codebase of its major implementation (XFree, forked into X.Org). Also a lot of the bad reputation of X11 should actually be attributed to Xlib, but Xlib ≠ X11

Comment: @datenwolf XRender actually allows you to "upload a font (glyphs) to the server"

Comment: @AndreySidorov: Yes, but only the glyphs, not a whole font. But a font consists of more than just the glyphs.